# how to use requirejs for non single page web apps?

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js, requirejs

Backbone is a must to organize our javascript code, I've been using it in non-singlepage applications but until now I've been structuring my codeigniter application as follows:

```
   /
   /profile
   /activity
   /....
```

Where some of the pages share javascript functions, backbone views,backbone models, etc

what i'm doing when I've javascript functionality that is shared across multiple pages is include it on a main.js

```
/profile
    ...jquery.js
    ...backbone.js
    ...other stuff...

...main.js   <--- shared scripts
...page.js   <--- specific page script (e.g profile.js)
```

The problem is when I've already a model that i would like to use in another javascript specific page (but not in all other pages) I've to replicate that piece of code into **other-page.js**.

That's annoying and a more scalable and modular solution would be great.
But i'm not used with require.js so I'm here asking for patterns that might help organizing my code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requirejs modules and create multiple modules for multiple pages and a common module for your common stuff:

- Each page uses a mix of common and page-specific modules.
- All pages share the same requirejs config.
- After an optimization build, the common items should be in a shared common layer, and the page-specific modules should be in a page-specific layer.

The configuration for this could be (build.js):

```
{
  // ther 'regular' configuration,
    modules: [{
        name: '../common',         
        include: ['jquery', 'app/lib', 'app/controller/Base','app/model/Base']
      },{
        name: '../page1',
        include: ['app/main1'],
        exclude: ['../common']
    },{
        name: '../page2',
        include: ['app/main2'],
        exclude: ['../common']
    }]
}
```

check out https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage for more details